# CSS Media queries not responding

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I know this question appeared here a few times, but I didn't find the answer I am looking for in them.

Basically I created web for 800x600 resolution, as I want to adjust web for different resolutions on desktop from this point. Before I go on, I want to ask, which is the best option, to use % or px for defining elements ?

So let's say I got web which I want to adjust to different resolutions. There is about 12 available of them for desktop. If I want that web to look properly on each, I should code it for each,right ? What is the best way to target screen resolution ? 800x600 works well, 1024x600 works too. However 1024x768, for some reason is not being targeted. Here I ll post the code:

```
.scene {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.fill {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: -1%;
  left: -2%;
  top: -10%;
}

.expand-width {
  width: 101%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 600px){}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 601px){

    body{background-color: red;}

        .fill {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: -1%;
  left: -2%;
  top: -10%;
}

    .expand-width {
  width: 101%;
}
    }
```

Comment: try zooming out to induce the "pseudo-higher rez"

Comment: just my bad, didnt copy it here. I ll edit that

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you are using media queries so % or px is not an issue as media queries is ther for resolving that issue only. but for true responsive ness you can go for %.

Next you are designing for 1024*600, so 1024*768 is included in it that's why ir is not effecting the code.

Try !important for 1024*768  resolution styles.

Comment: Actually I was hoping that max-height: 600px and min-height: 601px would distinguish between resolutions.

Comment: Nope, !important didn't do anything

Comment: Thats fine you can have that but you can't have 1024*600, so 1024*768 together..one style will rewrite the other

Comment: what are you writting `@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 768px){}` or `@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 768px){}`

Comment: @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 768px){} - this would apply to what I want. So, why does 1024x768 override 1024x600 ?

Comment: if you are using `@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 768px){} or @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 600px){}` then 1024x600 override 1024x768 but if you use @media only screen and `(min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 768px){} or @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 600px){}` then then 1024x768 override 1024x600

Comment: so to say, I cant define both width and height at the same time ?

Comment: you cant define height*width in such a way so that two media queries intersect

Comment: so if I type (max-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 768px) // (min-width: 1025px) and (min-height: 769px), will that work for both resolutions ? I suppose not...

Comment: No it won't one will override the other

Comment: How can I affect ,except of width, also height ?

Comment: Try like this--`@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (min-height: 701px){} or @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-height: 700px){}` then you can cover both the resolution

Comment: I ll try and let you know

Comment: Well it seems I managed to distinguish between resolutions with:

media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) and (max-height: 650px)
media only screen and (min-width: 1020px) and (min-height: 720px)

But for some reason, 1024x768 isn't affected by anything.